# Adding Watchkit to existing app - Concerns

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, apple-watch

I have an app I'm almost ready to publish. I would like to make a view for the watch for it but just wondering if there is anything I should consider first. From what I can tell if you add Watchkit to an existing iPhone app, it doesn't really affect the app as an iPhone app - is that right? Is there anything that changes on an iPhone app when you add Watchkit other than it will (after launch) show up in the Watch app store as well as the regular app store?

Should I publish first, then add Watchkit, then update? Maybe for purposes of it being published quicker? I'd like to be in the Watch store on launch day, is that possible?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your specifications. You can publish first your iPhone app without implement any WatchKit version, and then, update with a new version that includes the WatchKit extension.

You have to take into account that if you start a submission process, you can't start another for the same app until Apple approve or reject your app. Of course, you can reject the submission before Apple notify you, in order to upload your new version.